# UIImage to Sprite in cocos2dx?

Tags: uiimage, ccsprite, cocos2d-x-3.0

First I save image from URL in document directory:

```
NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:userImage];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image name.png"];

[UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:YES];
```

And then I want to retrieve this image in cpp as Sprite:

```
std::string writablePath2 = CCFileUtils::getInstance()->getWritablePath();
writablePath2.append("your saved image.png");
Rect rect2 = Rect(visibleSize.width/2 - 200, visibleSize.height/2 -200 , 500, 500 );
Sprite *screen_shot = Sprite::create(writablePath2,rect2);
screen_shot->setPosition(visibleSize.width/2 ,origin.y + visibleSize.height/2 - 100);
this->addChild(screen_shot,2);
```

But it is showing Black Sprite.

Comment: remove rect2, i think it will work.likes Sprite *screen_shot = Sprite::create(writablePath2);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)create Texture2D from file path

2)create Sprite fom  Texture2D

here is the code

```
std::string imagPath = CCFileUtils::getInstance()->getWritablePath();
imagPath.append("your image name.png");

Texture2D* objTexture2D = new Texture2D();
Image* image = new Image();

JpgImage->initWithImageFile(imagPath);
objTexture2D->initWithData(image->getData(),image->getDataLen(),Texture2D::PixelFormat::RGB888,image->getWidth(),image->getHeight(),Size(image->getWidth(),image->getHeight()));

Sprite *spr = Sprite::createWithTexture(objTexture2D);
spr->setPosition(origin.x + visibleSize.width/2 , visibleSize.height/2);
this->addChild(spr,2);
```

and here you go ....

Comment: Do we HAVE to go through the disk system to do this? It sounds like it could get terribly slow?